# What is the need of images in docker

Tags: docker, docker-image

I am just wondering, why having images is mandatory in docker. All the containers which are created on top of the image, can only see the file system that the image contains.

Why is it not possible to create the read write layer on top of the host operating system itself?

Comment: The purpose of Docker is to provide isolation and clear dependency management through an immutable image. A container with a read write layer on top of the host operating system would mean all files will be accessible and shared. This would decrease the reproducibility of that container.

Answer (score 0):

Think of an image as VM blueprint and a container as an instance of a VM

Very similar to how an object is an instance of a class

From 1 image you can create 100 instances of that image, very useful for scaling solutions

If you want to access files in another container you can use docker compose ... Set a volume on the container that has the files to share and set volume_from on the containers that will have access to the first containers files. We use this to share the same ssl certificates to all containers.

If you don't fancy using docker compose then just research volumes generally which allow access to the hosts file system.